# UITextField missing the paste functionality

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I can provide code if needed, however my problem looks fundamendal. I have a UITextField in a view that can copy and paste in it. After the action I cannot do it again. It works only once.

What might be the reason behind it? Is it possible that the paste menu is not shown because of another view in the window?

some code:

```
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,1,320,50)];
    [myTextField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:40]];
    [myTextField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myTextField setText:@""];
    [myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    [myTextField setEnabled:YES];
     [myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
    [myTextField setDelegate:self];
    myTextField.inputView = hiddenView;
```

and

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if(action == @selector(paste:))
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Do I need to add something in the viewWillAppear method related with the UITextField? As I said the first time works fine.

**UPDATE:** After the first paste the copy/paste/select mechanism stopped working on my application in ALL views...

Comment: Have you tried keeping finger pressed for some time on the textfield. And make sure your text field is first responder.

Comment: I don't have code about firstResponder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (sel_isEqual(action, @selector(paste:)))
    {
       return YES;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```